# Hindi text not rendered properly in android

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm working on an app where I have to show text received from a server response in a `textview`. The text could be in **`English or Hindi`**. In case of **hindi**, some of the letter are replaced by question marks `(?)`. What is the issue here?
This is how I set my text. **`Android version 6`**. Font type- Proxima Nova Alt Regular

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 viewHolder.lines[i].setText(poem.lines[i].lineText);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: give me your hindi text sample

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it seems that some letters are being rendered properly while others are not. This is obviously a font compatibility issue. Please download a new font for your version of the Android, if you want to use a custom font.

However, in many of the new Android devices (especially Android 6 and later), Hindi is supported by default. So in that case, just check `Settings -->  Language & input` of your phone. If Hindi is supported, then just change Locale of the app to Hindi and it should work.

```
Configuration.Locale = new Locale("hi", "IN");
```

Comment: Where to place this code "Configuration.Locale = new Locale("hi", "IN");"?

Answer (score -1):

Download Hindi Font From Here : http://fonts.webtoolhub.com/font-n17979-kruti-dev-010.aspx

put this font in "assets" folder : app/src/main/assets/kruti-dev-010.ttf

```
Typeface hindiFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.this.getAssets(), "fonts/Kruti_Dev_010.ttf");
    txtFont.setTypeface(hindiFont);
    txtFont.setText("एनडीटीवी इंडिया : हिन्दी समाचार की आधिकारिक वेबसाइट");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert the string into `UTF-8` like

```
viewHolder.lines[i].setText(URLDecoder.decode(poem.lines[i].lineText,"UTF-8");
```